# Protractor Debugging Issue - Waiting for the debugger to disconnect

Tags: node.js, protractor, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug protractor scripts on VSCode.

I edited the launch.json file but the debug console throws the below error.

Here is the VSCode Debug Console Output:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=45448 conf.js C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example/conf.js 

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:45448/ab61a2d7-4b40-456b-86cb-838e94dfe5b0

Debugger attached.

Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I am not able to find a solution anywhere online either.

Answer (score 0):

When you set your breakpoint in VSCode, you'll need to run the following:

`node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/protractor conf.js`

The path above assumes Protractor is installed in your `node_modules/.bin/` directory locally in your project.

Next navigate to `chrome://inspect`. You will have to skip the entry point of Protractor and then you should hit your breakpoint. Make sure you are using node 8 to avoid getting polyfill-ed promises.

We go over this in detail in the [ng-conf video](https://youtu.be/6aPfHrSl0Qk?t=16m18s). We kick off the test with [a script](https://github.com/angular-seattle/protractor-new-hope/blob/master/3-debugging.sh) that uses this [e2e-debug command](https://github.com/angular-seattle/protractor-new-hope/blob/master/package.json#L12) which is the equivalent to the above.