# Unable to debug Typescript for Protractor in VSCode with Node 8.x

Tags: typescript, debugging, automation, protractor

I am not able to debug Typescript (which compiles into JS for Protractor) when on Node 8.x. 7.x used the browser.pause() but that's not an option anymore since it is deprecated.

I am using the latest version of VSCode.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "bond",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "bond e2e automation tests",
  "author": "bond",
  "main": "./config.ts",
  "license": "bond",
  "scripts": {
    "webdriver-update": "npx webdriver-manager update",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "build": "tsc",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "test": "npm run tsc && protractor tmp/config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.0",
    "adm-zip": "0.4.7",
    "chance": "^1.0.16",
    "chromedriver": "^2.41",
    "colors": "1.1.2",
    "geckodriver": "1.8.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.99.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "0.4.0",
    "selenium-server": "^3.13.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.0.6",
    "xml2js": "~0.4.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.4",
    "protractor-beautiful-reporter": "^1.2.6",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "yarn": "^1.10.1"
  }
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "XPIA",
        "stopOnEntry": false, //debug exp
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\config.ts",
        // "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\tmp\\",
        "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "smartStep": true,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "protocol": "auto",
        "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/config.js"],
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/tmp/**/*.js"
        ]
    }]
}
```

This is just killing most of my time as I often switch to Node 7.x and use the inefficient browser.pause()

**Edit 1:**

As per the suggestions below, from the video, I am using Node 8.x, Selenium Promise Manager is false and targeting es2017, but got this error.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Error]

My complied code is in the tmp folder and not node_modules/protractor/bin

[image: node inspect and folder structure]

config.ts

```
import { Config } from 'protractor';
import { Environment } from './environment';
import { StandardSetup } from './Standard-setup';

var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');

export let config: Config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    directConnect: true,

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_NAME || 'chrome'),
        'version': (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_VERSION || 'ANY'),
        'shardTestFiles': true,
        'unexpectedAlertBehaviour': 'accept',
        'loggingPrefs': {
            'performance': 'ALL',
        },

        'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['--disable-notifications', '--disable-infobars', '--start-maximized'],
            prefs: {
                download: {
                    'prompt_for_download': false,
                    'directory_upgrade': true,
                }
            }
        },
    },

    specs: ['specs/proj/*test-spec.js'],
    seleniumAddress: 'http://10.10.113.153:4444/wd/hub',

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        isVerbose: true,
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 999999, //longer timeout for debugging
        print: function () { }
    },

    /**
    *  @returns logs to console on page load 
    */
    async onPrepare(): Promise<void> {
        let setup = new StandardSetup(),
            env = new Environment();

        setup.setSpecReporter();
        await setup.setjasmineReporters();


        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            baseDirectory: 'reports/screenshots'
         }).getJasmine2Reporter());

         return await env.setGlobals();
    }
};
```

**Edit 2:**

The command that I am using is:

```
node --inspect-brk ./tmp/config.js
```

[image]

Now I am able to see the config file in dev tools. However, when I press F8, the script is not pausing at the "debugger;" in the spec-file. All I am seeing is this:

[image]

To debug on VSCode (F10), I changed the launch.json:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}\\tmp\\config.js",
```

Again I am ending up on the config and getting nowhere near to the spec file.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is it the `program` in launch.json should be `${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor` ?  From Protractor official   site: http://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging `browser.pause()` should work on Nodejs 8

Comment: Please do not use `browser.pause()`. Also I answered this question previously. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601745/protractor-debugging-issue-waiting-for-the-debugger-to-disconnect/51604042#51604042 and also there's a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aPfHrSl0Qk&t=1209s

Comment: @yong The compiled code is in a tmp directory in the same project folder. Here's the folder structure

Comment: @cnishina I went through the video. Added more information and screenshots for your reference. Thanks for replying. Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please provide your Protractor config. I wonder if your spec is pointed in the right directory.

Comment: @cnishina I added the config.ts and the command that I used to debug the script.

Comment: @cnishina I added Edit 2 for the latest information.

Comment: Are you adding a `debuggger;` call?

Comment: Yes. I have added debugger; in the page objects file and the spec file as well.

Comment: Any suggestions @cnishina